# c++: no matching function for call, but the candidate has the exact same signature

Tags: c++, g++

g++ complains about

```
myclass.cxx:185: error: no matching function for call to 'IMyInterface::doSomething(const SomeClass*, unsigned int)'
IMyInterface.h:34: note: candidates are: virtual void IMyInterface::doSomething(const SomeClass*&, unsigned int)
```

when I call

```
m_instanceOfInterface->doSomething((const SomeClass*)0,(unsigned int)1);
```

Any pointers to why? It seems to me that g++ is seeing exactly the same signature between what is declared and what is being called, but still complains about no matching function found.

I can call, in the same context, another function of `IMyInteface`, `IMyInterface::doSomethingElse(float& p)`. So somehow the `const` is the problem?

---

I did not pass the NULL pointer and cast a constant integer just for fun... originally I have

```
m_instanceOfInterface->doSomething((const SomeClass*)m_someDerivedClass,m_anInteger);
```

and got the same error. So I decided to clarify things with g++ by giving some explicit arguments. I can assure you that the NULL pointer is NOT the problem - although understandably we all cringed a bit when seeing a NULL being passed with `const` :)

Comment: Does it work if you create the pointer before the function call? I mean `const SomeClass* ptr = 0;` and then `m_instance->doSomething (ptr, 1)`

Comment: PS: please add the function signature (declaration in the header), it could help...

Comment: That (i.e. creating pointer before call) solved the problem! But why g++ give such cryptic message?

Comment: There's a syntax error, you forgot a parenthesis. Also, why cast an integer? You can just say `1U`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Or just 1, period. The compiler is smart enough to know how to cast a positive `int` to an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @David: `template <typename T> foo(T, T); unsigned int bar(); foo(bar(), 1);` :-(

Comment: The error message makes it look as if there's only one candidate, taking `unsigned int`. But it's at least possible that the error message was truncated only to show the candidate that the questioner thinks ought to have matched, and there's also an `int` overload. Or will be in future. Not that you often have to worry about such things, but it would be wrong to suggest that `1` will always do.

Comment: You can also fix this by declaring the called function as `doSomething(const SomeClass *const &, unsigned int)`.  Also you do not need the `const` when you cast 0 to `SomeClass *` (although it does no harm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function requires its argument by non-const reference, which cannot bind to a temporary. Observe:

```
void foo(int, T &);
foo(1, T()); // error, cannot bind to temporary
```

In your case, `T = SomeClass const *`. So, you have provide a non-temporary:

```
SomeClass const * pc = 0;
m_instanceOfInterface->doSomething(pc, 1U);
```

Note that the purpose of this is presumably to fill `pc` with some meaningful value, so be sure to incorporate that apporpriately.

Comment: The temporary problem is head-on! It seems to be a very subtle problem to watch out for... do you have more reference to why it is implemented this way in the compiler?

Comment: @Polyglot: This is really fairly straight-forward: Passing a non-const reference means that you intend to modify the object (for otherwise you could have passed a const reference). But if you pass a temporary, all changes will be lost immediately at the end of the line! While that wouldn't be strictly *impossible* to implement, it would just *never* be useful and almost always wrong, so the language forbids it.

Comment: @polyglot: it's basically because the people who wrote the language thought it would be helpful for `void doSomething(unsigned int &a) { a += 1; }` to result in an error if you try to call it like `doSomething(1);` or even `doSomething((unsigned int)1);`. That call would modify a temporary that gets immediately discarded, and it was assumed (rightly or wrongly) that this isn't what you mean to do. It's especially error-prone since calling it like `int i = 1; doSomething(i);` would leave `i` equal to 1, whereas `unsigned int i = 1; doSomething(i);` would actually increment `i`. Bugtastic.

Comment: @Kerrek: actually, binding a non-const reference to a temporary has a potential use. It would allow a function like, say, `time()` (or anything else with an optional out-param) to take a reference parameter instead of a pointer parameter, and you pass in a temporary instead of null when you don't care about the result, and the implementation doesn't have to special-case null or provide overloads to make the parameter formally optional. So it's only *almost* useless rather than never useful, and I suppose the potential use wasn't considered to outweigh the likely bugs.

Comment: But the function signature declares `const`, so the caller should not expect the parameter to change, even though the param is passed by reference?

Comment: @Steve: I guess what I should have meant is that "there's always a way to design a function in which passing a modifiable temporary is useless". Dealing with legacy code is quite plausibly an exception. You could also envision a function to which you need to pass a reference to some memory in which the function does its work but which isn't needed again afterwards... `int x = compute(char[100]());` etc...

Comment: @polyglot: No aspect of the function signature declares anything as const. The type of the first argument is a reference to a *pointer to a constant object*, but that has nothing to do with the constness of the pointer itself, or of the function.

Comment: @polyglot: to back up what Kerrek just said, note that `void doSomething(const SomeClass* &ptrref, unsigned int) { ptrref = 0; }` is valid, it sets the pointer supplied by the caller, to null. `ptrref` simply is not const. It's possible that you meant to declare that parameter either as `SomeClass * const &` or as `const SomeClass *const &`, although there's not much point passing a const reference to a pointer since pointer is a small type, you might as well pass it by value for most purposes.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
Corrected to reflect comments.

The candidate does *not* have the exact same signature. The function takes a reference to a const pointer to a `SomeClass`, and you are providing a pointer. In fact, you are providing a particularly nasty pointer to the function.

One big problem here is that null pointer. You need to give the compiler something solid so it can take the reference of it. You are giving it a null pointer.

Comment: Is it possible to have a `NULL` reference (non-`const`)? It seems in most cases where you'd attempt that, it would be a compiler error rather than undefined behavior. Perhaps I just haven't thought of anything.

Comment: The function takes a reference to a pointer, not a pointer to a reference.

Comment: The reason I was passing a NULL and a constant unsigned int is because g++ is giving me that error for a more legitimate call. I modified the question to include the original call.

Comment: @Toolbox: Unfortunately, yes. It is of course UB, but that doesn't mean it isn't possible.

Comment: @Nicolas: You are correct of course. Those complex declarations need to be read right to left for the most part. The function expects a reference to a const pointer. Corrected, and thanks.

Comment: NULL pointer is not the problem (not the compiler anyways). See edits to question.

Comment: The problem is that it's a temporary, not that it's null. `const SomeClass *ptr = 0; doSomething(ptr, 1);` is allowed, even though `ptr` is null, assuming of course that `doSomething` doesn't dereference it by writing `*ptr`. `SomeClass *ptr = new SomeClass; doSomething((const SomeClass *)ptr, 1);` is not allowed, even though `(const SomeClass *)ptr` is not null, because the result of a cast (to non-reference type) is a temporary.

Comment: @David Hammen I think Steve's comment is getting at what I was asking. It seems like the closest thing you could get to a `NULL` reference that actually compiles would be a reference to a pointer that points to `NULL` -- which isn't UB until you actually dereference it. I think I just misinterpreted. :(

Answer (score 2):

Your function require a *non-const reference* to a pointer, not a pointer. You can't create a non-const reference from a literal (i.e. the null pointer), so the compiler is unable to call the function with the first argument being '0' and he looks for an overload taking its first argument (the pointer) by copy.